# Call to undefined method Smalot\PdfParser\Encoding::__toString()

Tags: php, pdf-parsing

I am using [Pdfparser Library](https://www.pdfparser.org/) for parsing pdfs. While parsing, Some pages of the 20-page pdf file are read and some pages are not. This is code I am using

```
$str_path = 'example_book.pdf';
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf = $parser->parseFile($str_path);
$pages = $pdf->getPages();
$page = $pages[7];
$text = $page->getText();
echo $text;
```

When I run the php script I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Smalot\PdfParser\Encoding::__toString()

Smalot\PdfParser\Font::translateChar
vendor/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Font.php:104
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps

1.open below mentioned file on the editor

> vendor\smalot\pdfparser\src\Smalot\PdfParser\Font.php

2. search for  function

> translateChar
> 3. Comment Out the below-mentioned code (or remove )
>
> if (\strlen($char) < 2 && $this->has('Encoding') && 'WinAnsiEncoding'
> === $this->get('Encoding')->__toString()) {
> $fallbackDecoded = self::uchr($dec);
> }

4. save file and exit.